# RecyclerView accidental scrolling on click

Tags: android, user-interface

When I click on recycler view several times, it scrolls to bottom on random clicks.

I suspect the issue is with emulator. My AVD is Nexus 5 API 27 x86.

**Question:** How to eliminate this random scrolling ?

Here is minimal example: https://github.com/OleksandrBezhan/RecyclerViewAccidentalScrolling

**Activity:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recycler.adapter = MyAdapter()
    }
}
```

**Adapter:**

```
class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    class ViewHolder(view: View, val text: TextView) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view, view.text)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.text.text = "Hello world"
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = 3
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Update:**
I added OnScrollListener and it shows that on accidental scrolls the scroll state goes to SCROLL_STATE_FLING and then SCROLL_STATE_IDLE.

Whereas under normal circumstances the scroll state should go to SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL -> SCROLL_STATE_FLING -> SCROLL_STATE_IDLE.

```
recycler.addOnScrollListener(object: RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
            override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, newState: Int) {
        Log.d("TEST", "onScrollStateChanged: $newState")
    }
})

D/TEST: onScrollStateChanged: 2
D/TEST: onScrollStateChanged: 0 
// 1, 2, 0 in normal scrolling
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with your GitHub project, tested on a Nexus 5X running Android 8.1. In that project, you have three items, each taking up the full size of the screen. I have tapped on the first item many times, and the `RecyclerView` does not scroll to the third item.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the try. Maybe OS can be the issue ? I'm getting this issue on OS X High Sierra.

Comment: I tried on hardware, not an emulator. Have you tried on hardware?

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried on hardware and it works well. It seems to be emulator issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an emulator issue, since there is no problem on real device.